# How can I order hours(am/pm) array

Tags: swift, sorting, dateformatter

Firstly I have to say this.

```
ÖÖ: AM
ÖS: PM
```

I have hours array like that:

```
[["12:15 ÖS", "02:00 ÖS"],["09:00 ÖÖ", "10:00 ÖÖ"],["10:30 ÖÖ", "12:00 ÖS"]]
```

How can I sort by first hour of the day?

```
 let testArray = [["12:15 ÖS", "02:00 ÖS"],["09:00 ÖÖ", "10:00 ÖÖ"],["10:30 ÖÖ", "12:00 ÖS"]]
    var convertedArray: [[Date]] = []

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en-US")

    for dat in testArray {
        let firstDate = dateFormatter.date(from: dat[0])
        let secondDate = dateFormatter.date(from: dat[1])
        if let firstDate = firstDate, let secondDate = secondDate {
            convertedArray.append([firstDate, secondDate])
        }
    }

    var ready = convertedArray.sorted(by: { $0.first?.compare($1.first ?? Date()) == .orderedAscending })
```

print(ready)

Comment: bcz I am living in Turkey.

Comment: we are using normally 24 hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take the first element and sorted after it

```swift
let testArray = [["12:15 ÖS", "02:00 ÖS"],["09:00 ÖÖ", "10:00 ÖÖ"],["10:30 ÖÖ", "12:00 ÖS"]]

let sortArray = testArray.sorted {
    $0[0] < $1[0]
}

print(sortArray) // [["09:00 ÖÖ", "10:00 ÖÖ"], ["10:30 ÖÖ", "12:00 ÖS"], ["12:15 ÖS", "02:00 ÖS"]]
```